# RestAPI data having multiple pages appends into single file during ADF pagination results in invalid json format

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have extracted the restAPI data which is in 10 pages using pagination in ADF (copy data activity). The problem is ADF seems to have is that when there are multiple pages, ADF just appends the different responses into one file.In my case I have 'results' as collection array and during pagination(10 pages), I can see the result which is json root('results') is getting repeated 10 times and this leads to an invalid JSON file. How to overcome this problem.Does ADF supports this?

Answer (score 0):

> RestAPI data having multiple pages appends into single file during ADF pagination results in invalid json format.

When you copy Data from Rest API to file with copy activity It will just append it as whole object ang you will get a set of objects which leads to a invalid json format.

To resolve this in sink setting there is `File Pattern` Option is available by default it is **set of objects** change it to **Array of objects** so it will convert it as array of objects and proper json format.

[image]

Comment: I have tried with array of objects.That's not working..its still same. What about mapping ? How mapping should be?